# Convergence of Distribution for a Modified Sequence of IID Random Variables

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, random-variables, random-walk

I have a sequence of IID random variables $S_i$ where $i = 1, 2, \dots, n$. Each $S_i$ can take values (-1, 1) with probability $\left(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}\right)$. As we know, the distribution of the random variable
$$ S = \frac{S_1 + S_2 + \dots + S_n}{n} $$
when $n$ approaches infinity, $S \sqrt n $ will approximate the normal distribution because of central limit theorem. Now, consider another set of random variables
$$ T_i = \frac{S_i}{i} $$
where $i = 1, 2, \dots, n$. Define T:
$$ T = \frac{T_1 + T_2 + \dots + T_n}{n} $$
what will be the distribution of $ T \sqrt n $ when $n$ approaches infinity?

Comment: Doesn't $(S_1 + \cdots + S_n)/n$ tend to zero almost surely by the law of large numbers?

Comment: Because central limit theorem, the distribution of S will approach to normal distribution.

Comment: @david no, $S$ does not converge to a Gaussian as $n\to\infty$, it degenerates to zero. $S\sqrt{n}$ however does tend to a normal distribution.

Comment: @Stratossupportsthestrike, you are right.

Comment: @Stratossupportsthestrike, what will be the distribution of $T\sqrt n$ when n goes to infinity  ?

Comment: My first thought would be to try to apply [Lyapunov's Central Limit Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem#Lyapunov_CLT), but unless I made a mistake it seems like the Lyapunov condition is not satisfied here. You might try and see whether the characteristic function converges pointwise.

Comment: @Stratossupportsthestrike, I will try Lyapunov's CLT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variance of $T_i$ is $\frac 1{i^2}$ and so $\text{Var}(\sum_{i = 1}^n T_i) = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac 1{i^2}\to \frac {\pi^2} 6$.

This means that as $n$ goes to $\infty$, the variance of $\sqrt n T$ goes to $0$, so $\sqrt n T$ converges to $0$ in $L^2$. This implies that $\sqrt n T$ goes to $0$ in distribution.
As $T = \frac{\sqrt n T}{\sqrt n}$, $T$ also goes to $0$ (in $L^2$/ distribution).

Generally you want your limiting distribution to have non-zero, but finite variance and $\sum_{i=1}^\infty T_i$ should have that, but I am not sure whether that will lead to a normal distribution: The characteristic function of $T_i$ is $\cos (\frac t i)$, so the characteristic function of the sum is a product
$$
\prod_{i = 1}^n \cos \left( \frac t i\right)
$$
and you'll have to check whether this converges pointwise to a continuous function of $t$ (continuous at $0$ suffices).

Here is some simulation code (in R) that shows what happens with $T$ and $\sqrt{n} T$ as $n \to \infty$:

```
Si <- matrix(rbinom(1000 * 100, 1, .5) * 2 - 1, 1000)
Ti <- Si*1/seq(nrow(Si))

T <- apply(Ti, 2, cumsum)  / seq(nrow(Ti))
sqrtn_T <- sqrt(seq(nrow(T))) * T

par(mfrow=c(2,1))
matplot(T, type='l')
matplot(sqrtn_T, type='l', ylab = latex2exp::TeX("$\\sqrt{n} T$"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-10-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for the answer. How is about the distribution of  T itself ? When n approaches to infinity, will T approach to a normal distribution ?

Comment: Please see my updated answer.

Comment: "$T$ also goes to 0(in $L^2$/ distribution)", this conclusion is not true. The correct one is "as $n\to\infty$, $T$ converge a.s. and in $L^2$(also in distribution) to a random variable $U$, $U$ is not a normal distributed".

Comment: @JGWang I don't think so: $T$ is the mean of all $T_i$, not their sum. If $\sqrt n T$ goes to $0$, then $T$ will as well (dividing by $\sqrt n$ only makes the convergence faster).

Comment: @Stefan, do you mean that the distribution of T and $ \sqrt n T$ both will approach Dirac delta function as n approach infinity ?

Comment: @david yes, both $T$ and $\sqrt{n} T$ will go to $\delta_{0}$ in distribution, I have added some simulations that also show this.

Comment: @Stefan, Thank you for your great help. What will be the distribution for $$ T_1 + T_2 + \dots + T_n $$ when n approach to infinity ?

Comment: @Stefan: For $$ T = T_1 + T_2 + \dots + T_n $$, I verified that, it does NOT satisfy Lyapunov conditions for Central Limit theorem, which implies that T may not approach to normal distribution when n goes to infinity. On the other hand, when I did numerical simulations, it seems that T does approach to normal distribution when n goes to infinity. Why ?